# csv load into Neo4j and create relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a csv file with below columns and sample data provided, and I've loaded into Neo4j and got stuck when I was trying to create relationships.

```
**source destination miles**
a         b         5
a         c         6
a         d         20
```

Now I want to create a graph with source in middle and connected destinations around and label with miles between two stops.(A star graph with source in middle), so I tried below queries, it's not returning miles on the label, I'm new to Neo4j, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///sample.csv" AS line
CREATE (s:src{id: line.source}) 
CREATE (d:dst{id: line.destination}) 
CREATE (s)-[r:trips {total: [line.miles]}]->(d)
RETURN s, d, r;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `LOAD CSV` expects the CSV file to use comma separators, and it does not support extraneous whitespace. Try changing the content of your CSV file to this:

```
source,destination,miles
a,b,5
a,c,6
a,d,20
```

Also, you should use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` to avoid creating duplicate nodes. And there is no evident need to store the miles value in an array, so this query stores it as a scalar value:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///sample.csv" AS line
MERGE (s:src {id: line.source}) 
MERGE (d:dst {id: line.destination}) 
CREATE (s)-[r:trips {miles: line.miles}]->(d)
RETURN s, d, r;
```

The result of the above is:

```
╒══════════╤══════════╤══════════════╕
│"s"       │"d"       │"r"           │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════════╡
│{"id":"a"}│{"id":"b"}│{"miles":"5"} │
├──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│{"id":"a"}│{"id":"c"}│{"miles":"6"} │
├──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│{"id":"a"}│{"id":"d"}│{"miles":"20"}│
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: No problem. Also, since you now have >=15 reputation points in StackOverflow, you can [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) answers as well. Congratulations :-).